# How can I make lastpage footer subreport overflow?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a subreport in detail band and a subreport in last page footer band. The subreport in detail is repeatable and page can overflow, but the subreport in the last page footer cannot be overflow.

How can I make the subreport overflow in the lastpage footer band?

Comment: Please don't add the irrelevant tags. iReport is just a GUI designer (not supported at present moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **not**, the last page footer has fixed height, if it would be able to overflow, it could not ensure that it is on last page....

You need to re-think your report design, probably the subreport needs to moved to the summary band or in a fake group footer.

To generate a fake group you pass a fixed `groupExpression` to the group, this way it will only be executed once.

Then use the `footerPosition` attribute to push the `groupFooter` band to bottom, to understand the different position depending on other groups in reports see [FooterPositionEnum](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/FooterPositionEnum.html)

**Example**

```
<group name="fake" footerPosition="StackAtBottom">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA["fake"]]></groupExpression>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="50"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
```

Comment: I do have something already in the summary band which can overflow. But what is fake group footer and also will fake group footer can overflow. How can I setup a fake group footer.

Comment: @ravigaddam I have updated post, note however that the summary band is after... so in generale think about where and how to put your different subreports, note they can also be one after the other one in same band (clearly it will not render  at bottom of page, if this is really what you need)

Comment: Thank you Petter, Its working fine now. But I have a problem with your solution. The content from detail band and groupFooter does not start from a fresh page. The data is displayed continuously. I want the data from groupFooter and detail band to be on new page.

Comment: Use the page break element or the attribute  isStartNewPage="true" on the group element, all depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have set attribute isStartNewPage="true" on the group element but still its not working. There are vehicles rendering in the detail band so I need each vehicle information on the new page in the detail band. The summary of all the vehicles in the groupFooter should be on the new page. But at the moment the vehicles information are printing continuously and followed by vehicles summary of groupFooter

Comment: Continuously?, with no pages?, or random page breaks?

Comment: random page breaks

Comment: It's hard to say whats wrong in report without seeing jrxml, have you seen the break component?, hence you can add a page break component.